# How to choose values from either of two columns based on patterns in on other column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame as follows:

```
       x<-c(1,8,2,4,3,1)
        Y<-c(2,3,4,1,7,6)
        z<-c("abs_ro","xyz_be","hdh_ro","ahh_ra","dhhd_te","hdj_ro")
        df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I want to create a new column values of which be selected from either of two columns x or y based on patterns in column z. If values in column z ends with "_ro" OR "_be" code chooses value from x, and if it ends with "_ra" OR "_te" the values form y be chosen. x

`I tried many ways like grepl, grep, etc. no one worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be various way of doing this. One way using base R assuming you would always have one of the pattern for `x` or `y` column.

```
df$value <- ifelse(grepl("_ro$|_be$", df$z), df$x, df$y)

df
#  x y       z value
#1 1 2  abs_ro     1
#2 8 3  xyz_be     8
#3 2 4  hdh_ro     2
#4 4 1  ahh_ra     1
#5 3 7 dhhd_te     7
#6 1 6  hdj_ro     1
```

---

Or if there could be multiple patterns we can also use `case_when`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(str_detect(z, "_ro$|_be$") ~ x, 
                           str_detect(z, "_ra$|_te$") ~ y, 
                           TRUE ~ NA_integer_))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a vectorized way without relying on any `ifelse`

```
df$value <- df[-3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), (!grepl("_(ro|be)$", df$z)) + 1)]
df$value
#[1] 1 8 2 1 7 1
```